# creating global string array through its own class, but still not recognized in different class method C#

Tags: c#, global-variables

Created a simple class with one element, a string [] array and filled it with elements.  I want to be able to add and delete elements in this array anywhere in my application, but it is not accessable.  been trying variations for two days so coming to the best for help.

```
enter code here
   public static void TestSlots()
    {
        String currentBehavior = _core.GetVariable("$_current_name", false);
        bool success1 = _core.ApiApp().SetDiagOutput("MYWARNING " + currentBehavior + " is");
        int indexNumber = MedIntents.medIntents.IndexOf(currentBehavior);
        ;
        if (indexNumber < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            //Global.MedIntents.RemoveAt(indexNumber);
            bool success = _core.ApiApp().SetDiagOutput("MYWARNING " + currentBehavior + " removed");
        }
        //now check if they asked or hit more than one important entity
        return;
    }


    // Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}

internal class MedIntents
{
        public string[] medIntents = new string[] {
        "any_chills",
        "constant_or_intermittent",
        "gradual_or_sudden",
        "had_them_before",
        "how_often",
        "howdoesitstart",
        "hurt_elsewhere",
        "nausea_or_vomitting",
        "numbness",
        "pain_relief",
        "relation_to_food_or_medical",
        "scaleofone2ten",
        "warning_signs"
        };
```

Comment: `medIntents` is an instance member. You may want to convert it to a [static member](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/static-vs-instance-members-csharp#module-staticpropertiesandfields-anchor). To prevent modification, you can add the `readonly` modifier.

Comment: `IMedIntentable`'s a great name for an interface; I'd use DI just so I could fill my constructors with it :)

Answer (score 0):

medIntents is an instance member. You may want to convert it to a static member. To prevent modification, you can add the readonly modifier. – Crafted Pod 2 hours ago

Comment: While this worked, I cannot remove a member of the list, nor replace it with a different string

Comment: Did you add the `readonly` modifier? It was only suggested if you don't need/want to modify your array. If it is not suitable for your use case then remove it. The problem with changing data in this manner is that you won't know what state your array could end up in, which can lead to unexpected behaviour and bugs. You could do what @caius-jard suggested and make a copy of the array, leaving the original untouched.